# Rspec - test redirection on unknown db record in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I am developing a Rails 3.2 application and want the user to be redirect to a custom error page at errors#index when he tries to find a non-existing db record.

This is my code to do this inside the application controller:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  rescue_from Exception, with: :display_error
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :display_error
end

private
def display_error
  render "errors/index", status: 404
end
```

This actually works fine in production mode. Now the question is, how do I test it beforehand? I have tried this:

```
it "leads to error page on unknown db record" do
  Rails.stub(:env).and_return("production")

  # Sign in
  @valid_user = FactoryGirl.create(:valid_user)
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in "Email", with: @valid_user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: @valid_user.password
  click_button "Sign in"

  # Trigger exception
  visit physician_path id: "this is not an id"
  assert_contain "You blew it!"
end
```

However, this leaves me with two errors:

- `undefined method 'development?' for "production":String` on `visit new_user_session_path`
- `Couldn't find Physician with id=this is not an id` on `visit physician_path id: "this is not an id"`

The first one seems to imply an error with mocking the production environment; the second one will hopefully go away once I have implemented the actual code.

How can I solve these two errors? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Rails.env` stores an `ActiveSupport::StringEnquirer` rather than a plain string: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3096629d297a77a9b64747a0ac2df6b2cbf47a68/railties/lib/rails.rb#L81

It might be easier to just stub the `production?` method:

```
Rails.env.stub(:production?).and_return(true)
```